# Mongoose: How to filter based on both a model field and associated model fields at the same time?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, associations, mern

I have model `User`:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "profiles",
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

I have model `Profile`:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  },
  institution: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "institutions",
  },
  videoURL: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

As you may have noticed the two models are associated with each other by referencing each other in `profile` and `user` field respectively.

I am trying to write a function that would get me the list of institutions of users of a certain country who uploaded a video and then filter that list with a `institution_search_pattern`:

```
const getListOfInstitutionsOfUsersWhoUploadedVideosByCountry = function getListOfInstitutionsOfUsersOfWhoUploadedVideosByCountry(
  country_name,
  institution_search_pattern
)
```

However, this seems like an expensive operation I will have to:

> 1. Search users of country_name by using mongoose find with a field filter and populate the `profile.institution` and `profile.videoURL`
>    fields
> 2. Filter with normal javascript functions on the returned array of users by `user.profile.videoURL` where `videoURL` is not `undefined`
>    or `null`
> 3. Create an array of the list of institutions of those users by using `user.profile.institution`
> 4. Filter again in the created array with the `institution_search_pattern` provided by the user by using a fuzzy search module
> 5. Send back in response the filtered institutions list

Is there a way to perform all of this with mongoose queries without resorting to filtering with javascript functions or modules?
For example, can I use a filter on the User model based on a Profile Model field?
In other words, in one single query:

1. Filter User.country with a country_name
2. Filter by Profile.videoURL where videoURL is not undefined or null
3. Filter by Profile.institution with a pattern **(1)**

**(1):** Filtering institutions by a pattern means:

1. The user sends a string search_pattern
2. I use that string to perform a fuzzy search on the institution field.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** based on comments: "Removed all `institutions` related code."

```js
const country_name = "India";

const users = await UserSchema.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { country: country_name }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",
            let: { profiles_id: "$profile" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        videoURL: { $nin: [undefined, null] },
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$profiles_id"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "profiles"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$profiles" }
]);
```

Why are you maintaining `users` reference in `profiles`? Its redundant. Instead have a reference to `profiles` only in `users` collection. All the tasks that you mentioned can be performed in single query. Check this query (change it precisely to your requirement):

```js
const country_name = "India";
const institution_pattern = /^Insti/;

const users = await UserSchema.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { country: country_name }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",
            let: { profiles_id: "$profile" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        videoURL: { $nin: [undefined, null] },
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$profiles_id"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "institutions",
                        localField: "institution",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "institution"
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$institution" }
            ],
            as: "profiles"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$profiles" },
    {
        $match: {
            "profiles.institution.name": {
                $regex: institution_pattern,
                $options: "i"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5"),
    "country" : "India",
    "profiles" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5"),
        "institution" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b2"),
            "name" : "Institute 1"
        },
        "videoURL" : "http://abc1.xyz"
    }
}
```

Test data:

`usres` collection:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5"),
    "country" : "India"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b9"),
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b6"),
    "country" : "India"
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152ba"),
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b7"),
    "country" : "U.S"
}
```

`profiles` collection

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5"),
    "institution" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b2"),
    "videoURL" : "http://abc1.xyz"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b6"),
    "institution" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b3")
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b7"),
    "institution" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b4"),
    "videoURL" : "http://abc3.xyz"
}
```

`institutions` collection:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b2"),
    "name" : "Institute 1"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b3"),
    "name" : "Institute 2"
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b4"),
    "name" : "Institute 3"
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much. The reason I am doing a double reference is in order to be able to access the user document and the profile document in both directions using populate.

Comment: By the way, I removed all the institution code, in order to try to get users of country who have uploaded video but it's returning all users and if they have a video it fills profiles field. Any idea why? (I am doing this because the searching in institutions will be done separately not with regex).

Comment: Filtering users where country=country_name and user.profile.videoURL must exist

Comment: It's the same code above. I just removed everything related to institutions. I don't think this is the right approach though. But, I just wanted to give it a try.

Comment: It still returns the list of users who don't have a videoURL.

Comment: Ok found the problem instead of `videoURL: { $exists: true }` we need to use `videoURL: { $nin: [undefined, null] }` check the updated answer.

Comment: It worked thank you so much. I'd buy you a coffee if I could.

Comment: No issues. Thanks!

Comment: Hey again, this all works. But, I would like the query to return the array of insititutions instead of all the users info so that I don't have to extract the list of institutions myself from the users info. Is there a way to do this directly?

Comment: Its difficult to write the exact query with out looking at your collections. Post some actual/dummy documents with expected output.

Comment: You can use the example of documents you provided. They follow the exact same structure I have. In the end, I am keeping the same query but I want the end result to be [instiution_name_1,institution_name2...etc]

Comment: I have found a way by adding this to the end :{
      $project: {
        institution: "$profile.institution.name",
      },
    },

Comment: That works, but the reason I asked for documents is because, documents from my sample data have 1:1 association and there no need to display institution as array.

Comment: 1:1 association means one institution is linked to only one profile. But you are asking for an array of institution names.

Comment: This means a lot. Thanks.